# I got no Inbox notification for a comment, why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467377/306023) answer, I already got a notification for the comment [`@MarcusLinsner - only gnu sed can do that via the e flag... – don_crissti yesterday`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467369/how-to-change-the-line-a-string-is-found-on-with-the-output-of-another-program-t/467377#comment851641_467377), but I got no notification for the comment [`the output from qx(...) includes a trailing newline, and the current line already has one. – glenn jackman yesterday`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467369/how-to-change-the-line-a-string-is-found-on-with-the-output-of-another-program-t/467377#comment851658_467377).

I looked at Inbox's `all items` (which for me is at this url: https://stackexchange.com/users/14170288/marcus-linsner?tab=inbox ). I searched(from Firefox) in all 3 pages for the text `the output from` but got no results; I also searched for `How to change the line` (which is the beginning of that question's title) and only found two notifications: 1. for the question getting [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467377/306023) and 2. for the [first comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467369/how-to-change-the-line-a-string-is-found-on-with-the-output-of-another-program-t/467377#comment851641_467377) from don_crissti which I already mentioned above)

**EDIT:** I just noticed that there was an [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/467377/2) for [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467377/306023) yesterday, that I got no notification for - but I am unsure if the system does dispense notifications for edited answers.

What happened / why? Should I expect this to happen again or was it just a one time fluke?

Comment: ah, I even received NO notification for an answer that was edited after I edited it :D Not a fan :) because [subsequent edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/29221/5) COULD break .. the answer; and since I get no notification of subsequent edits, I've no chance of detecting any such breakage (in that case: using `head -n 1000` in place of `head -z -n 1000` in that context is breakage for filenames containing `\n` and for limiting to 1000 file names - now there's no limit and is basically counting 1000 file names containing '\n' in their name instead of counting number of filenames).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first comment replied to you by name using `@MarcusLinsner` -- that's not just a convention, the site recognizes it and knows that the reply is for you:

[image]

If a reply doesn't contain a specific `@name` target, it's assumed to be a reply to the post's author; in this case since the comment was *by* the post's author, it didn't alert anyone.

There's a special case where if a post's author comments and there's only one other person in the comment thread at that point, the site assumes the author was replying to the other commenter even if they didn't specify, but it doesn't apply in this case because there was a third person in the thread (don_crissti).

There's lots of info on the subtleties of the comment reply system in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/145982).

---

As for the part about edit notifications, there are notifications for "non-trivial" edits to posts, which [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135411/145982) defines as at least 10 characters, or 2 characters if within a code block. But those notifications only go to the post author, not everyone that commented on the post.